# Drupal 8 Gutenberg module is preventing edits to existing webform elements and add new ones

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, wordpress-gutenberg, drupal-webform

I have a Drupal 8.9.6 site with Gutenberg 8.x-1.11 and Webform 8.x-5.20.
When we go to edit an existing webform elements, or add a new element, we get the following error:

```
    Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::getFields() in gutenberg_entity_presave() (line 621 of /code/web/modules/contrib/gutenberg/gutenberg.module)
    #0 [internal function]: gutenberg_entity_presave(Object(Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform), 'webform')
    #1 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php(403): call_user_func_array('gutenberg_entit...', Array)
    #2 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityStorage.php(349): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll('entity_presave', Array)
    #3 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(500): Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage->invokeHook('presave', Object(Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform))
    #4 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(454): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPreSave(Object(Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform))
    #5 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityStorage.php(263): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(Object(Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform))
    #6 /code/web/modules/contrib/webform/src/WebformEntityStorage.php(133): Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage->save(Object(Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform))
    #7 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityBase.php(395): Drupal\webform\WebformEntityStorage->save(Object(Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform))
    #8 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityBase.php(616): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->save()
    #9 /code/web/modules/contrib/webform/modules/webform_ui/src/Form/WebformUiElementDeleteForm.php(217): Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase->save()
    #10 [internal function]: Drupal\webform_ui\Form\WebformUiElementDeleteForm->submitForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
    #11 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormSubmitter.php(114): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #12 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormSubmitter.php(52): Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
    #13 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(593): Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
    #14 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(321): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('webform_ui_elem...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
    #15 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/FormController.php(91): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object(Drupal\webform_ui\Form\WebformUiElementDeleteForm), Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
    #16 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch))
    #17 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #18 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(573): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
    #19 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
    #20 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)
    #21 /code/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(151): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
    #22 /code/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
    #23 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
    #24 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
    #25 /code/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
    #26 /code/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
    #27 /code/vendor/asm89/stack-cors/src/Asm89/Stack/Cors.php(49): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
    #28 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Asm89\Stack\Cors->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
    #29 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
    #30 /code/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
    #31 /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(708): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
    #32 /code/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
    #33 {main}
```

I have attempted to create an account on drupal.org but my requests are blocked.
Any thoughts on why this would happen? Should I try the alpha versions of both on a dev site and see if that fixes it? I did not attempt to edit the modules directly.

Comment: Looks like files aren’t found. Check your setup.

Comment: Also, this site is got community attention: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/